# PHP: When submitting an HTML form, does the HTTP_REFERER get set?

Tags: html, http

An exception was thrown in my application, but the HTTP_REFERER was null, which seems strange in this case. I'm wondering if you could answer a quick question:

So I've got this form:

```
<!-- mysite.com/index.html -->

<form action="http://mysite.com/somewhere/else">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When someone submits the form, I am expecting that the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` will be set to `/index.html`. Is that true?

Comment: You can use Firebug to monitor HTTP requests. Very helpful :)

Comment: this question is not specific about PHP. It depends on you client software (Browser) not your server software (i.e. PHP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is the value of the **optional** HTTP [Referer](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.36) header.  This header is set by the browser.

The browser can opt to not set it or to lie about it, such as Firefox's [RefControl](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/953) addon does.  Thus, you *cannot* rely on it to be present, or even accurate.

If a browser does give it, it will most likely not be `/index.html`, but rather `http://www.mysite.com/index.html`

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I just tested it with both HTTP POST and GET and the Referer header was sent by the client (Google Chrome) both times.

This might be browser specific behaviour though.

EDIT:

In case anyone cares, here's a simple way to test it in PHP:

```
<?php
    echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
?>
<form method="post"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>
<form method="get"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Referrer is *usually* sent, so, you can expect it.
But you cannot **rely** on it, as it's only on the client's will - to send it or not.
And many clients don't.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you type in the URL, the browser won't set the referrer, but if you come from another page (click through or form post), the browser should set the referrer variable.  This variable should be read and parsed by PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when the POST is sent but not necessarily when the page is first loaded. You can always verify this by looking at your logs ('tail -n 10 file.log' will give the most recent 10 entries). The referrer part (for a dummy PHP form site.com/php-form/) below is in bold:

192.168.1.10 - - [16/Apr/2008:16:12:36 +1200] "GET /php-form/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2014 "**http://www.referringsite.com/**" Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Konqueror/3.5; Linux) KHTML/3.5.8 (like Gecko)"

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

```
'HTTP_REFERER'
The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.
```